# How to create an object in a situation where the type is only known at runtime?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

I have two product classes, Line and Trunk which both require getServiceFee and setServiceFee functions that return/manipulate their serviceFee member variable.

1. how do I create a Line or Trunk in a situation where the type of object is only known at runtime
2. how do i write a function  which is passed the object to be updated assuming I do not know whether the object passed to it is a Line or a Trunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where Interfaces comes in handy.

Create an Interface with a setter and getter for the `serviceFee` property:

```
interface SomeInterface 
{
    public function getServiceFee();

    public function setServiceFee($fee);
}
```

Make sure both classes implements that interface, and add the setter and getter:

```
class Line implements SomeInterface
{
    protected $serviceFee;

    public function getServiceFee()
    {
        return $this->serviceFee;
    }

    public function setServiceFee($fee)
    {
        $this->serviceFee = $serviceFee;
    }
}

class Trunk implements SomeInterface
{
    protected $serviceFee;

    public function getServiceFee()
    {
        return $this->serviceFee;
    }

    public function setServiceFee($fee)
    {
        $this->serviceFee = $serviceFee;
    }
}
```

In the method that manipulates the serviceFee, type hint the interface and use the getter and setter. Now it doesn't matter object is of the type Line or Trunk. As long as it implements the interface, you can be sure that the getter and setter exists:

```
class SomeClass
{
    public function someMethod(SomeInterface $instance)
    {
        $fee = $instance->getServiceFee();

        // do stuff

        $instance->setServiceFee($fee);

        return $instance;
    }
}
```

To dynamically create instances, you can do this (you do need to know what type to create at *some* point, though):

```
$type= 'Trunk';

$instance = new $type;
$instances->setServiceFee(1234);

$someClass = new SomeClass;
$instance  = $someClass->someMethod($instance);
```

Comment: I would also add, that, if `Trunk` and `Line` instance have different dependencies themselves, then the `$instance = new $type` should probably be replaced by a call to DIC (or, maybe a service locator, if the architecture is lacking).

Comment: @tereško True. I just didn't want to go into containers and such in this answer, since we have no clue what the OP's setup actually looks like. I agree that using Dependency Injection Containers is the way to go, though. But calling a DIC directly to get an instance is not DI, that's just using it as a service locator, no?